# Flush messages to Chronicle Queue

Tags: chronicle, chronicle-queue

I'm using Chronicle Queue v5.17.0 to process messages and my understanding is that the queue does not lose messages even if the java process dies (due to the fact that queue uses memory mapped file which is flushed by the OS).

Will some messages be lost if the VM dies or OS crashes before it flushes memory content to file?

Is there a way to control messages flush to disk?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, If the data has not been flushed to disk it will be lost. There are also no guarantees that the disk that you are writing to has not become corrupted.

Even a force flush to disk cannot be relied on, as such, if you wish to guarantee that no messages are lost we recommend that you use chronicle-queue-enterprise to replicate your queues data to another host, Once the acknowledgement has been received ( for each message ) you now have a safe copy of each message, for more information on chronicle-queue enterprise please contact sales@chronicle.software